# Mongodb Mongoose complex query for search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement a dynamic search bar that shows suggestions based on what the user types in. Example you start typing "j" and you see options such as "Java, JavaScript, JQuery" ... then you type "ja" and only see "Java, JavaScript".

My schema looks like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    text : String,
    answers : Array,
    tech : String,
    tags : [String],
    level : String,
    createdAt : Date
});

// Return the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Questions', QuestionSchema);
```

And I need the search to look for matches in 'text', 'tech', 'tags', and 'level'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go

```js
let query = [
        { 'text': { $regex: new RegExp(keyword, "i") } },
        { 'tech': { $regex: new RegExp(keyword, "i") } },
        { 'tags': { $regex: new RegExp(keyword, "i") } },
        { 'level': { $regex: new RegExp(keyword, "i") } }
    ]

    Question.find({ $or: query }, function(err, results){
...
    });
```